# Подскажите почему не выводит props Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Не могу вывести props в консоль. Именно в функциональном компоненте.

В классовых все работает нормально. Вроде подключение к redux есть. Единственное что пишет, это то что props undifined

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export function listСategories(props) {
  const string = 'Hello world';
  console.log(props.gamedata.numQues);
  return string;
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  gamedata: state.questions.data,
  user: state.user.data,
  screen: state.screen.screenState,
  allquestions: state.allquestions.data,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(listСategories);
```

Вот в классовом все нормально:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { styles } from '../styles';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Progressbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    let result = [...Array(this.props.gamedata.numQues)].map((item, index, arr) => {
      let color;
      if(this.props.gamedata.right.includes(index)){
        color = 'green';
      }else if(this.props.gamedata.wrong.includes(index)){
        color = 'red';
      }else{
        color = 'blue';
      }
    return (
          <View key={index} style={{width: 20, height: 20, borderRadius: 100/2, backgroundColor: `${color}`, marginBottom: 10}} />
    )
  });

    return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      {result}
    </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  gamedata: state.questions.data,
  user: state.user.data,
  screen: state.screen.screenState,
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Progressbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

В функциональном компоненте не используйте this. Вы же props аргументом получаете

```
export function listСategories(props) {
  const string = 'Hello world';
  console.log(props);
  return string;
}
```

Comment: Все равно undifined